# What does "Signing off attribution" mean?

Tags: terminology, contracts, attribution

I'm about to sell a range of images to a client and he asks me for a document to "sign off attribution". What does this mean and where can I find sample contracts?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like he wants you to sell him some type of agreement to either reprint, or use the images as you agree to. An example of attribution from the [creative commons license](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Creative_Commons_Attribution):

> Under the Creative Commons Attribution license, commonly abbreviated as CC-BY, you are free:
>
> to Share — to copy, distribute and transmit the work
> to Remix — to adapt the work
> Under the following conditions:
>
> Attribution — You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor (but not in any way that suggests that they endorse you or your use of the work).

If you are looking for examples I would take a look at this previous question already here:

> [What resources can you suggest to help me write contracts?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11702/what-resources-can-you-suggest-to-help-me-write-contracts)

Comment: That's the Creative Commons Attribution (CC BY) license. I know you link to it, but it's still important to clarify, as many people are under the mistaken impression that there's only one CC license.

Comment: I already noted that its the CC-BY license. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: It's just the phrase "the creative commons license". I've seen lots of people claiming that their blog, or their pictures, or whatever are under "the creative commons license", with no indication of which license they mean, so that phrasing jumps out at me.